# Prevent page from reading changes made by extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extensions which will make some changes to a page using an injected content script. I don't want the page to reverse these changes or read them. Is there any way I can do that?

If it's not possible with content scripts, is there any other way to do it in a chrome extensions?

Comment: Anything you change in the DOM is available to anyone. What exactly are you "changing"?

Comment: I want to change the content of some elements and prevent the page from reading the changed content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't lock your DOM changes from further modification by the page, there's nothing you can do to prevent the page from reverting any changes your extension makes. The best you can hope to do is capture any events and attempt to block or reverse, but anything like that is likely to be very code intensive.